# replacing dijit.ComboBox with dijit.Select results in error (ArcGIS Javascript API)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, select, dojo, ios, combo-box

I am currently populating a Dojo ItemFileReadStore with the results of an ArcGIS query (Javascript 3.4 API), which is then passed to a Dijit COmboBox.
I am now having problems with the ComboBox in iOS (see http://grokbase.com/t/dojo/dojo-checkins/132kx1h9jj/dojo-toolkit-16730-combobox-long-drop-down-lists-broken-on-ios). It looks like a dijit.Form.Select might work (although not ideal, b/c there is no autoComplete or placeholders); It works fine on my iPhone for the dropdown lists that I hard-coded.  But I am getting an error that I believe is related to the ItemFileReadStore, and the results of my query are not being passed into the select dropdown menu.

In my HTML, I tried simply replacing ComboBox with Select:

```
    <select id="Select" dojotype="dijit.form.Select"
    value="" class="comboBoxClass"  onchange= "setName(this)"
```

My store is still set up the same way as I had before:

```
    var dataItems = {
    identifier : 'name',
    label : 'name',
    items : values
};

var menuStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    data : dataItems,
    clearOnClose : true
});
```

...and the Select box is given the store's values the same as before:

```
    dijit.byId("menu").set("store", menuStore);

menuStore.fetch({
    onComplete : completed,
    onError : error,
    sort : sortAttributes
});
```

I added:

```
  dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");
  dojo.require("dojo.parser");
```

to my init file...

But I am getting this error in Firebug:

```
  dojo/parser::parse() error
  TypeError: _7.getLocalization(...) is undefined
```

In Chrome there is also an error with dojo/parser:

```
 message: "Cannot read property 'missingMessage' of undefined"
```

(I also tried swapping ComboBox with FilteringSelect, but the iOS problems are the same.)

Ideas?
note, this question is somewhat of an extension to an earlier question I had regarding specifically the iOS issue with the Dijit ComboBox ([combobox GIS SE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82965/dojo-combobox-problems-on-iphone5-arcgis-js-api))...I would happily, actually rather, still use the ComboBox if there is some way to make it work properly on an iPhone! but I can live with the Dijit.form.Select box if that is what I must do....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/93470-Suggestions-for-debugging-a-dojo-parse-error) which gave the primary reason this wasn't working: apparently with versions 3+ of the ArcGIS JS API (using Dojo 1.8+), dijit layout forms can break the code if there is a 'lang' tag in the HTML, which I had.  No more parse error after I deleted this tag.
Also, more dumbly, I was not explicitly assigning the option values when I switched from ComboBox to Select dijits.  For the ComboBox, it was sufficient to simply assign the dropdown options as "`<option>thing</option>"`...but for the Select dijit I needed `"<option.value="thing">thing</option>"`.  Without this change, I was not firing the onchange event when selecting an option using a Select form.
Also, to create the store using dijit.form.Select, I needed to edit the syntax to set the store:

dijit.byId("menu").setStore(menuStore);

Now my Select dropdown menus work, but sadly they still are wonky on iPhones and Androids!