# Dojo TypeError for ArcGIS Javascript API App

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I recently updated the app to the [3.13](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/whats_new.html) framework, and now am getting the following error when I load my application.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'missingMessage' of undefined
```

Chrome says the error is being thrown on the [Select Dijit](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Select.html).  I do not have "lang" in my HTML tag [(like this error)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83001/replacing-dijit-combobox-with-dijit-select-results-in-error-arcgis-javascript-a).  Anyone have any ideas?

```
var querySelect = new Select({
    id: "querySelect",
    name: "querySelect",
    options: [
        {label: "Signs", value: "signs", selected: true},
        {label: "Bridges", value: "bridges"},
        {label: "Culverts", value: "culverts"},
        {label: "Drains", value: "drains"},
        {label: "Roads", value: "roads"}
    ]
}, "query_select").startup();
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the simplifed code:

```
<script src="query.js"></script>    //Script with Select Dijit  
<script>
    var map;

    require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "esri/config",
        "esri/IdentityManager",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "esri/map",
        "esri/toolbars/draw",
        "dojo/dom-construct",
        "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
        "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
        "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
        "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle",
        "esri/dijit/Geocoder",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
        "esri/Color",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/graphic",
        "esri/tasks/query",
        "esri/geometry/Extent",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/dom-style",
        "dijit/form/CheckBox",
        "esri/tasks/IdentifyTask",
        "esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters",
        "esri/InfoTemplate",
        "esri/dijit/Legend",
        "esri/request",
        "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
        "dojo/dom-construct"
    ], function (parser, esriConfig, IdentityManager, BorderContainer, ContentPane, Map, Draw, domConstruct, HomeButton, Scalebar, webMercatorUtils, BasemapToggle, Geocoder, GraphicsLayer, FeatureLayer, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, Color, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Graphic, Query, Extent, Point, GeometryService, on, dom, domStyle, CheckBox, IdentifyTask, IdentifyParameters, InfoTemplate, Legend, esriRequest, DataGrid, Memory, ItemFileWriteStore, domConstruct) {

        parser.parse();
```

Comment: are you calling parser.parse()?  can you provide a link to a simplified repro case?

Comment: Yes I am calling parser.parse().  The select dijit is contained in an external .js file. parser.parse() is called in <head> of index.html.  I bet the select dijit is being parsed before parser.parse() is called.  Is there a way to solve this when using external js files?

Comment: no need to 'bet'.  set breakpoints in both locations to get more familiar with the actual flow of code.  also, id still like to see a simplified repro case.

Comment: I added the code as it appears in my app, I am not sure if this is what you were looking for, if not let me know what you need and I can send it

Comment: by repro case, i mean a complete code example thats ready to run and doesn't include anything that isnt necessary to show the problem.  whats in your `query.js`?  isn't the problem reproducible when you comment out all those other unrelated modules?

Answer (score 1):

With the code you had to create the Select, it creates the Select object and immediately runs the startup() method on that dijit. The startup() method does not return the Select object. It only runs processes after the dijit is loaded on the HTML DOM and visible. Therefore, your querySelect variable doesn't receive anything. Here's a better way to handle it.

```
var querySelect = new Select({
    id: "querySelect",
    name: "querySelect",
    options: [
        {label: "Signs", value: "signs", selected: true},
        {label: "Bridges", value: "bridges"},
        {label: "Culverts", value: "culverts"},
        {label: "Drains", value: "drains"},
        {label: "Roads", value: "roads"}
    ] 
}, "query_select");

// now call startup on the querySelect.
querySelect.startup();
```